# Generate Sequence in a pyspark dataframe such that it increments when a value is found after nulls

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, sequence

I have a time series data, looks something like below. All I need is to generate the Sequence column for only 'Low' values. Also sequence should increment only when there is a change in 'MODE' value.

I am trying to do this using pyspark. Ideas or actual code to implement will be really appreciated.

[image]

Thanks,
Nash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something like this before using SQL and have translated it to Spark SQL, and if you are okay with that it is easy enough to create a temp view -> spark.sql and then go back to a data frame. I am sure it is also easily done in Pyspark.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("data") # Name your temp view
query = """
SELECT time, temp, pressure, mode, CASE WHEN mode='Low' THEN sequence ELSE NULL END FROM (
  SELECT *
  , SUM(increment) OVER(order by time) as sequence
  FROM (
  Select *
  , CASE WHEN mode!='Low' and LEAD(mode) OVER(order by time) != 'Low' THEN 0
    WHEN mode='Low' AND lag(mode) OVER(order by time) = 'Low' then 0
    WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN mode='Low' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) over(order by time) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  as increment -- Don't want to start incrementing if there aren't any "lows" yet, like rows 1 and 2 in your table
    FROM data -- the name of your temp view
  )
)
"""
dfSequence = spark.sql(query)
```

In the above query, the sequence= null if the mode is not 'Null', per the example you provided above.